# Trigger causing Maximum trigger nesting level exceeded

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have created a new trigger that updates my `[Purchase Table]` if the number of delivered items equals the ordered quantity, but every time it's run I get the following error.

> ODBC--update on a linked table 'dbo_Purchase Table' failed. 
> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32). (#217)

This is the trigger that I have created:

```
USE [####]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trUpdatePurchaseTableStatus]
    ON [dbo].[Purchase Table]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        UPDATE PT
        SET PT.Delivered = 1
        FROM inserted as I
        INNER JOIN dbo.[Purchase Table] AS PT
        ON [PT].[ID] = I.[ID]
        WHERE PT.deliveredQTY >= PT.QTY
    END
```

Comment: You're updating the same table, so the trigger fires again... Forever. You need a way to stop of firing a second time.

Comment: if you want to update the same table, you can try to use an `instead of` trigger

Comment: Why not use a computed column for `Delivered`? There's no need for a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: @NayanishDamania of course you can, but you need to find a way to prevent recursion.

Comment: Side note, don't suffix your objects with things like `Table` and especially don't put spaces in their names. The object names `Purchase` would be far better, and you wouldn't have to delimit identify it every time you need to reference the object.

Comment: @Larnu The tables were set up before I started so I can't do anything about that. I don't know what a computed column is.

Comment: It's a column that is computed; you don't specify the value for it, it's calculated: [Specify Computed Columns in a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value of `Delivered` is purely based on if the value of `deliveredQTY` is greater than or equal to `QTY` I would suggest using a computed column instead, then you don't need a `TRIGGER`.

You can't change an existing column to be a computed column (you can't even `ALTER` a computed column) you would need to `DROP` the column and then add it:

```sql
--You would also need to DROP any CONSTRAINTs and/or INDEXes, etc, that use the column
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Purchase Table] DROP COLUMN Delivered;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Purchase Table]
ADD Delivered AS CONVERT(bit,CASE WHEN deliveredQTY >= QTY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /*PERSISTED*/; --If the column is to be indexed, you'll likely want the PERSISTED
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

**The real answer here is to use a computed column**, [like @Larnu says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71703896/14868997).

---

However, if you really want to use a trigger for this, you can place the following code at the top to bail out early

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trUpdatePurchaseTableStatus]
    ON [dbo].[Purchase Table]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID, 'AFTER', 'DML') > 1
  OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;

UPDATE PT
..........
```

Comment: Curious why not @@NESTLEVEL which doesn’t require mentioning the name

Comment: Because the trigger may have been fired from another trigger: we should not stop that. `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL` with a parameter prevents recursion. By the way, another pet peeve of mine: procedures and triggers should not have a `BEGIN END` surround block, as the whole batch is the procedure, it just confuses people otherwise

Comment: Ok so like SCOPE_IDENTITY > @@IDENTITY. I’m thankful I don’t have to deal with nightmare trigger scenarios.

Comment: Oh I disagree with that, I am a big fan of the block wrappers, because they’re another scenario where you often do need them and NOT having them can cause confusion. People have to learn regardless, and in my experience the GO stuff is far more confusing than begin/end.